# Обновление элементов select без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать обновление элементов select из базы данных по нажатию на `<a href=''><img src='refresh.png'></a>` без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать для этих целей функцию getJSON.
Что-то типа этого:

```
var url="get_data.php?param1="+param1;
$.getJSON(url,{}, function(data){
    for (var i=0;i<data.tbldata.length;i++)
        {
alert (data.tbldata[i].id);
}
});
```

в get_data.php:

```
$param1=$_GET["param1"];
 $outp="{\"tbldata\":[";
 $query="select id from `table`";
 if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
 {
 if ($result=mysqli_query($link,$query))
 if ($outp != "{\"tbldata\":[") {$outp .= ",";}
 $outp .= '{"id":"'.$row["id"].'"}';
 }
 }
 $outp.="]}";
 echo $outp;
```

**Обновление**

[[@kiberchainik](/users/4108/kiberchainik)](/users/4108/kiberchainik), a если подумать? ;-) Вместо alert тут может быть любой код. Я показал пример. А тебе нужно

```
 $('#my_select').append('option value='+data.tbldata[i].id+'>'+data.tbldata[i].id+'<option>);
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: не совсем понимаю Ваш запрос, и alert это ведь всплывающее окно, а мне нужно обновление option в select'e

Comment: А если подумать? ;-)
вместо alert тут может быть любой код. Я показал пример.
А тебе нужно $('#my_select').append('option value='+data.tbldata[i].id+'>'+data.tbldata[i].id+'<option>);
Так понятнее?

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо, если бы можно было, угостил бы пивом )))

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать ajax.

Пишеш обработчик, который будет генерить код вида 
`<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>` и т.д. Самому селекту задаешь id и при нажатии на рефреш посылаешь ajax запрос на файл-обработчик, а результат, который возвращается, записываешь в селект.

`$("#ваш_ид").html("то_что_вернется");`

Comment: еще уточните мне, как вернуть из php обработчика ответ обратно в ajax, чтоб передать его элементу? json_encode(то что возвращаем)?

Comment: можете просто вывести, без json_encode